# Comparison of Stahel-Donoho and Minimum Covariance Determinant estimation

Tags: estimation, outliers, robust

I am interested in detecting multivariate outliers in a low dimensional data set ($n>p$). Various high-breakdown robust methods for multivariate settings such as Stahel-Donoho and Minimum Covariance Determinant estimation is proposed in the literature. Can you give an advice and make a comparison than which estimator should be used and why?

I have just found out that, due to computationally intensive calculation of Stahel-Donoho, the MCD estimation is preferable. How can I realize the intensity of calculation? Is there other reason for the superiority of MCD?

Comment: "due to computationally intensive calculation of Stahel-Donoho, the MCD estimation is preferable." Can you cite the source for this claim?

Comment: https://uwaterloo.ca/statistics-and-actuarial-science/sites/ca.statistics-and-actuarial-science/files/uploads/files/2009_multivariate-robust-control-chart-for-individual-observations.pdf

Comment: https://theses.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-07302003-183651/unrestricted/Chapter3.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both algorithms have high quality implementations in a common environment so we can actually compare their running times. 
Check the [`CovSde`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rrcov/docs/CovSde) and [`CovMcd`](http://www.inside-r.org/node/72039) functions in [`rrcov`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rrcov/index.html).

[Both algorithms have an argument `nsamp` which plays a similar role for both and impacts their computing times in a comparable way. Nevertheless, in the `rrcov` package the `nsamp` argument has different default values for the two algorithms, so in order for these comparisons to be fair, you'll need to make sure you are using the same values of `nsamp` when running both of them by setting it manually.]

To answer your question proper. Fixing the `nsamp` parameter to the same value, the running times of both algorithms now only depends on the size of the input matrix $\pmb X$. Denote $n$ ($p$) the numbers of rows (columns) of $\pmb X$.

The numerical complexity (and running times) of both algorithms scales roughly the same way as a function of $p$ (so the number of variables is not the culprit).

However, for large values of $n$, the running times of FastMCD scales less than linearly with $n$. This is due to the so called nested sub-sampling algorithm included in the FastMCD (section 3.3 of [0]) --CovSde has no comparable nested sub-sampling scheme.

The actual value at which the nested sub-sampling algorithm kicks in is set by the user but the default value is $n=600$. For large values of $n$, the nested sub-sampling algorithm can lead to substantial computational savings for FMCD.

You can see the effect of the nested sub-sampling algorithm by comparing the running times of both algorithms for $n<600$ (when neither uses nested sub-sampling):

```
library(rrcov)

n <- 600
p <- 8

nsamp <- 1000
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nc = p)
system.time(CovMcd(x, nsamp = nsamp))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.116   0.000   0.114 
system.time(CovSde(x, nsamp = nsamp))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.084   0.000   0.082
```

to their relative running times when $n>600$ and FastMCD's nested sub-sampling scheme kicks in:

```
n <- 6000
p <- 8

nsamp <- 1000
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nc = p)
system.time(CovMcd(x, nsamp = nsamp))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.160   0.016   0.170 
system.time(CovSde(x, nsamp = nsamp))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.188   0.012   1.197
```

- [0]: P. J. Rousseeuw and K. van Driessen (1999) A fast algorithm for the minimum covariance determinant estimator. Technometrics 41, 212--223.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. but is it possible to provide more clarification on this part _It is however true that for large values of n, the running times of FastMCD scales less than linearly with n_

Comment: Which output of system.time function can be used as a comparison criteria? use, system or elapsed?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688949/what-are-user-and-system-times-measuring-in-r-system-timeexp-output). I'll pass by latter to add more clarification on that part.